# R Studioでパッケージをインストールするときのエラー

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudioはVersion 1.0.136です。
多項ロジット分析をやろうと思い、mlogitというパッケージをインストールしようとすると、以下のエラーが出ました。（***はパソコンの所有者名です）

```
install.packages("mlogit")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/***/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘statmod’
Warning in install.packages :
  lzma decoding result 10
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
```

そのため、同じ機能をもつであろうVGAMというパッケージをインストールしようとしても同じようにエラーが出ます。これは何がいけないのでしょうか？

```
install.packages("VGAM")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/***/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  lzma decoding result 10
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
```

Comment: Windows 環境ですので、`install.packages("mlogit", type="win.binary")` とすればインストールできるかもしれません。リポジトリに Windows 向けのコンパイル済みバイナリが用意されていれば、ですが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。下記はどういう意味でしょうか？

>リポジトリに Windows 向けのコンパイル済みバイナリが用意されていれば

Comment: リポジトリによってはソースコードだけしか置いていない事があります。